# How do I pull a local insecure registry image in a rancher service?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, rancher

1. I have two VMs (OS ubuntu desktop), one is [rancher server](http://docs.rancher.com/rancher/v1.0/zh/installing-rancher/installing-server/) (192.168.72.128) and other machine has docker registry (192.168.72.139) using  [portus](https://github.com/SUSE/Portus).
2. The configurations are all correct, I add a registry into the rancher with proper credentials.

> ```
>     Name              Hostname    
> mydocker-registry 192.168.72.139:5000
> ```

3. From the rancher server, I can do a docker login to the docker registry, and I can do a  docker pull 192.168.72.139:5000/myimage successfully.
4. However when I try to add the service image through the rancher UI it shows this error:

> ```
> Error (Image [mydocker-registry/myimage:latest] failed to pull: 
> Error: image mydocker-registry/myimage not found)
> ```

But I can see the image using portus UI at : http://192.168.72.139:3000/. Does any one have a clue as to why this maybe happening ??

Edit: 5/7/2016 (5.12 pm) :  If I try to use the registry's proper hostname address in the rancher UI (rather than registry name) when starting a service, I get the following errors. I am not sure as to how to use this then ?

> Error (500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("unable to ping
>   registry endpoint https://192.168.72.139:5000/v0/ v2 ping attempt
>   failed with error: Get https://192.168.72.139:5000/v2/: tls: oversized
>   record received with length 20527 v1 ping attempt failed with error:
>   Get https://192.168.72.139:5000/v1/_ping: tls: oversized record
>   received with length 20527"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it without the SSL by adding the insecure option to the docker daemon clients???

First you need to stop the docker service and then execute
    sudo docker -d --insecure-registry 192.168.72.139:5000

or add the flag "--insecure-registry 192.168.72.139:5000" to the docker daemon service so when you start the docker service the flag is active.

You can check if the flag is active by looking the ps

```
ps -aux | grep docker
```